# Share image with FileProvider or MediaStore

Tags: mediastore, android-fileprovider

I have to following problem. I want to share an image using intent chooser to the as many apps as possible. To achieve that I have two options:

1. Save the image to `MediaStore`. But that means that image will show up in the gallery without user's granting it.
2. Or share the image using using `FileProvider`. But if I use `FileProvider` some apps don't work and throw the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.
>               at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
>               at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
>               at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
>               at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:106)
>               at ehz.a(PG:175)
>               at duj.a(PG:540)
>               at com.google.android.apps.photos.phone.SendContentActivity.onClick(PG:177)
>               at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Working `FileProvider` would be perfect for me because with `.nomedia` option I can hide the image from Gallery and still share image to all the other apps.

Did anyone manage to solve this? Is there another option to share an image that can be accessed to all the other apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Saved the problem. Instead of all the options I've used `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` and created subdirectory with `.nomedia` and it worked.

Comment: Make any progress on this?